# Metro/Modern UI/UWP apps stuttering on external monitor at 144Hz

Tags: windows, windows-10, modern-ui, uwp

I have a **BenQ EX2780Q** monitor (1440p@144Hz capable) connected to a gaming laptop running Windows. I have Windows set to use the second screen only which is this external monitor. In normal circumstances, everything including apps and games run fine at 1440p and 144Hz which is the native resolution and refresh rate of the monitor.

If there's a power cut (or if the mini-DP cable is unplugged and plugged back in), the EX2780Q monitor turns off and Windows switches to the built-in display of the laptop (which natively displays 1080p@144Hz). When power is restored, Windows switches back to using the external monitor again. However, when this happens I notice that the Metro UI/UWP apps like Windows Store, the start menu, Windows Explorer, certain games like Valorant, etc. start micro stuttering which is very annoying and distracting, especially while in-game.

How do I fix this micro stuttering issue? I must mention that this only happens when my external monitor is connected and isn't reproducible when I'm using the laptop's built-in 1080p, 144Hz display.

Since it's hard to explain the issue with just text, here are links to short videos I captured of my monitor when the issue is seen as well as when it's not observed. Both videos were captured using a smartphone recording in 1080p@60FPS

**Dragging the Windows Store app - Micro stuttering observed**
[image]

**Dragging the Windows Store app - No micro stuttering observed**
[image]

P.S. I might have mis-diagnosed the issue and it may occur with non-metro apps as well

---

**EDIT:** Added still frames extracted from the videos to better describe the issue to anyone who hasn't watched the videos

*Micro-stuttering: **YES***
[image: Micro-stuttering: YES]

*Micro-stuttering: **NO***
[image: Micro-stuttering: NO]

Comment: Is that a DisplayLink (note: Link, not Port) display?

Comment: @Spiff I don't think so, no. If it is, it's not advertised as such and from DisplayLink's website their tech seems to be used in USB monitors.

Comment: If it helps, the gaming laptop is a MSI GE75 Raider 9SG. Link to spec sheet: https://www.msi.com/Laptop/GE75-Raider-9SX/Specification

Comment: Also, here's a link to the monitor's spec sheet: https://www.benq.com/en-us/monitor/gaming/ex2780q/specifications.html

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question since I figured out a reliable fix for this issue.

There are at least two ways that worked in fixing this issue. Neither is a permanent fix, unfortunately and the problem re-surfaces every time there's a power cut or the monitor's mini-DP cable is unplugged and plugged back in.

1. **Restart the PC**

   The most obvious fix is to restart the computer while the external monitor is still plugged in. This works but wastes a lot of time since restarting isn't fast or ideal
2. **Restart Desktop Window Manager process (dwm.exe)**

   While trying out a bunch of different things that didn't work, I thought of restarting `dwm.exe` as a hail mary and that fixed the problem. This can be done via the Task Manager (find `dwm.exe` in the *Details* tab and click <kbd>End task</kbd>) or via an elevated command prompt with the command `taskkill /f /im dwm.exe`